# Interpolation from WFS point layer

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wfs, interpolation

In QGIS, I added a WFS-Layer from my geoserver, containing few point data with a numeric attribute (Z-values).

This works fine, and all the points display on the map.

Now I just assumed, I would be able to do a quick IDW Interpolation from the Raster -> Interpolation menu. But in the interpolation ui, I can't choose an "Interpolation attribute" from my wfs layer, because the dropdown is empty.

[image]

If I do the same from an csv file containing the same data, it obviously works fine.

Has anyone an idea, why this shouldn't work? Do I miss the point here?
Is it because of this operation is not supported for wfs layers or is it about my adjustments?

Comment: Works fine for me with QGIS 2.12 on Windows. Only fields of type Int can be used for interpolation. Does your WFS layer have integer fields?

Comment: Thanks for that hint. Will check if that works. I tested with 2.8 and double values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment from user30184 I recognized, that all fields in my geoserver layer were not really of numeric type, also I assumed this. After changing field type to real/double in database (which is float in geoserver feature type description), I could do the interpolation of a layer column.

This works according to my tests from at least QGIS 2.8.2 onwards and with float values as well.